# I want to get all the result where moddate is one day back from today

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the below query I get all the result with current date :-

```
select count(*) 
from   KLG_RKS_PKH..WorkHist 
where  modname ='HR' 
and    moddate = convert(date,Getdate())
and    revokedate = null
```

I want to get all the result where `moddate = moddte - 1` .The result should be one day previous to present day i.e. yesterday and only for yesterday.

can someone help

Comment: Start with removing the unrelated tags.

Comment: What is the datatype of `moddate`

Comment: I guess you have to replace `GETDATE()` with `DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())'.

Comment: By the way, which DBMS are you actually working with? MySQL, SQL-Server and Oracle have slightly different syntax and functions.

Comment: The fact that OP is using the CONVERT function leads me to believe this is for SQL Server.

Comment: The OP's previous question with the same schema was just tagged [MySQL]. The same old story: it's "urgent" but not urgent enough to frame a proper question so people can answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server then just use the dateadd funtion like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   KLG_RKS_PKH..WorkHist
WHERE  modname = 'HR'
AND    moddate = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()))
AND    revokedate is NULL
```

in case that moddate is not declared as type date than use this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   KLG_RKS_PKH..WorkHist
WHERE  modname = 'HR'
AND    CONVERT(date, moddate) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()))
AND    revokedate is NULL
```

Comment: Is `= NULL` a valid SQL Server comparison?

Comment: its working thanks a lot my friend i was making a silly mistake :(

Comment: Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @GuidoG's answer.  This is rewards the contributor for their efforts, and helps others to find a working solution.

Comment: Hey guys how to get all values in a single cell.. suppose I am getting the below result from query in a table employee:- employee  name   salary    . Now I want to get the result in way that i will get all the values in one cell like   emplyee,name, salary.... any idea

Comment: I do not understand this question. Can you please explain a bit more what you want ?

Comment: How get the result of the below scenario:- suppose a participant is getting terminated in oct. So i want to get this into report on the base of the logic" end day of the month plus 30 days" measn any particpant who is getting termed on 8 or 9 oct then it should come on the report after end day of the  oct + 30 days i.e. 30Nov

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some sample data and the desired result. Maybe than it will be more clear to understand what you mean